# How to add custom js file after footer in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, layout, footer

While creating custom theme, I need to add custom js file after footer. How can I do that in Magento2 ...pls help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If this is helpful to anyone, it is possible to move all the JS `<script/>` tags after footer tag.
Execute below command.

`php bin/magento config:set dev/js/move_script_to_bottom 1`

Clear cache and all the `<script />` tags will move after `<footer />` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can call **external JS file link** via

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="exampleScript">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.example.com/example-script.js"></script>]]></argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

if would you like to call **custom module file.** So you can call custom phtml file and call your custom JS file.

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Namespace_Modulename::before.phtml" name="before_body_js"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

add template file before.phtml add below code

```
<script src="your js path" />
```

Comment: i am having my js file..so instead of " src="//www.example.com/example-script.js" " what i have to write and where to write

Comment: @SUBBULAKSHMIG First way to add external JS file link, Ex. Any third party server link. You can continue with "custom module file" option.

Answer (score -1):

Find `page.xml` of your theme and find the following

```xml
<block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
```

And insert the following just before

```xml
<block type="page/html_head" name="jsfooter" as="jsfooter" template="page/html/jsfooter.phtml">
   <action method="addJs"><script>your_script.js</script></action>
</block>
```

Create the template file in 
`app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/page/html/jsfooter.phtml`

and put the following in jsfooter.phtml:

`<?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?>`

And put this: `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('jsfooter') ?>`

In your page template files “1column.phtml”, “2columns-left.phtml”, “2columns-right.phtml”, “3columns.phtml” in which you want. you will need to output this block before tag

Comment: He wants for magento 2.

Comment: yes i want for magento2